# Why is the Back-Forward Cache disabled in Microsoft Edge by default?

Tags: microsoft-edge, chromium, browser-cache

Recently I've been fixing an issue related to the Back-Forward Cache; Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari all have the Back-Forward cache enabled without the need to enabled it via a setting/flag. Microsoft Edge (I've been testing on versions 111 & 112) despite being Chromium based has an additional `Enable Back/Forward Cache` (see [edge://flags#edge-enable-bfcache-features](https://edge://flags#edge-enable-bfcache-features)) flag which is `disabled` by default.

Is there any documentation on the experimental feature, why it's disabled and information on the roadmap for enabling it by default?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I searched but can't find any doc about this flag. I think that's by design in Edge. If you have any concern about this feature or have any suggestion about this feature, I suggest you can provide feedback to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge. They'll check the feedbacks and improve the product continuously. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: it's obivously by design, but that doesn't tell me why or what the status of the feature is. Chrome started rolling out the bfcache in version 46, I'm just looking to find out what's going on since it's a bit strange that Edge is the only browser not supporting this feature by default.

Comment: There's no public documentation about this, so I suggest you provide feedback. Or you can also ask the question in [Edge Insider community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-edge-insider/ct-p/MicrosoftEdgeInsider) to see if you can get more help.

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten about the Insider boards. I've posted the same question there: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/why-is-the-back-forward-cache-disabled-in-microsoft-edge-by/m-p/3797488